# How to restore all the tabs that were open in Windows, after a reset, shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, workspace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore open applications, documents, and window state](https://superuser.com/questions/158795/restore-open-applications-documents-and-window-state)

Is it possible to reopen all the applications, Folder explorer windows, and all other windows which were open prior to a windows restart.
I keep lot of tabls open on my taskbar, which i need, and it's kind of pain to remember al of them and reopen them again after a windows restart. 
Basically can windows/some other app which can be isntalled, remember what all I had opened and reopen the same after restart? 
I am using Windows 7 64bit.

If windows doesn't allow it, Any third party tool/app to do this?

Comment: I don't believe Windows has this ability built-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore open folders in Explorer by checking the option to restore previous folder windows a logon in Folder & Search options. This only works for open folders in Explorer, though, not every app.

[image: Windows Folder Options][image: Restore folders]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well developed this is, but it may be worth a try:
[Cache My Work](http://cachemywork.codeplex.com/)

There are a few reviews for it available too, just Google for them.  I'd give you a link, but I'm to new here to post more than one in an answer!

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this is 64bit on second thoughts.. Still worth a look though to find out.

Comment: It's .NET and FAQ Question 2 says so, also: "CacheMyWork is only able to cache your applications, not their documents; It's not able to save and automatically re-open the open documents for most applications; CacheMyWork is only able to cache the first instance of each application that it finds." I first thought the program would capture the memory state which would allow this to do that, but it's actually hard to perform as you need to override the kernel so it just works by tracking the target line instead... For me this just looks like the built-in feature "run once" rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just use the built-in features [Hibernation or Sleep](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions)?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your question, but should you be looking for internet tabs restoration as well, the Opera browser has a very functional automatic session save/load. You can set it up so it never prompts you about this.